# DHCP request with no answer

Tags: cisco

I have a problem with GNS3 router DHCP . I'm using a Cisco 1700, VMware, and Windows 7 which are connected by a cloud.

I configured DHCP on the router, and the DHCP binding works; I can see the DORA process in Wireshark, but the host gets an APIPA address.

Does anyone have any idea what may be wrong?

Comment: How do you configure the cloud in gns3?if you do configure ip manually it will work?

Comment: @Mr.lock yes it worked if i configure ip manually. 
thanks for fast reply :)

Edit: and about the cloud i just put the vmware 1 network card and also like this in the machine

Comment: Did you bridge it with loop back?  Disable any running firewall and check

Comment: @Mr.lock Disabled all firewalls , on the vm and in the real machine, still not work.
bridge with loop back ? what?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score -1):

i think the firewall block the DHCP, disable your firewall. and maybe you have active packet filter in router.